# Inserting date-type values into the table in Oracle: ORA-00984

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables created according to the following diagram:

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlCbr.png)

I am now trying to populate those tables with the test data and I'm having trouble inserting date-type column into the PositionLogEntry table getting an error: PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here.

```
declare
```

noOfFlights   constant int:= 10;
noOfLog       constant int:=100;

begin

for m in 1..noOfFlights loop

insert into Flight (aircraftRegistration, DateAndTimeDeparture,pilotInCommand)
values              (
                    'Aircraft Registration' || to_char(sqFlight.nextval),
                    to_date('2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
                    + to_ymInterval(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(1,30))) || '-' || to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(1,12)))),
                    'Pilot in Command' || to_char(sqFlight.currval));
                    end loop;

for c in 1..noOfLog loop
    for m in (select AIRCRAFTREGISTRATION, DATEANDTIMEDEPARTURE from Flight) loop

insert into POSITIONLOGENTRY (AIRCRAFTREGISTRATION, DATEANDTIMEDEPARTURE, logTime, positionLatitude, positionLongtitude, courseDegrees, headingDegree, horizontalSpeedKnots,
  verticalSpeedKnots, altitudeFeet, altitudeFlightLevels) values
  (
    AIRCRAFTREGISTRATION,
    DATEANDTIMEDEPARTURE,
    to_date('2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
    + to_ymInterval(to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(1,30))) || '-' || to_char(floor(dbms_random.value(1,12)))),
    round(dbms_random.value(7,0)),
    round(dbms_random.value(7,0)),
    round(dbms_random.value(3,0)),
    round(dbms_random.value(3,0)),
    round(dbms_random.value(3,0)),
    round(dbms_random.value(3,0)),
    round(dbms_random.value(4,0)),
    round(dbms_random.value(4,0)));
    end loop;

end loop;

/*commit;*/

end;
/

P.S. The Flight table gets populated correctly.
Could you please suggest any possible fixes?
Thanks!

Comment: If this is an Oracle post, why do I see MySQL tag there?????  Tag properly!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use column names: `AIRCRAFTREGISTRATION, DATEANDTIMEDEPARTURE` etc in `VALUES` clause.

use

```
m.AIRCRAFTREGISTRATION,
m.DATEANDTIMEDEPARTURE
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But now I'm having another issue:

Comment: ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.SYS_C0010701) violated
ORA-06512: at line 22
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

Comment: @MarcusStenberg : This is unrelated to the question and is occurring because you are inserting duplicate values on a column with a unique constraint. You will have to figure that out why it is happening.We may not be able to help you here as it could be data / coding logic issue.